# Putting date before URL in misc citation? And spacing between arguments of citation

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

```
@misc{Bamboo:Density,
title = {Engineering Toolbox},
author = {``Wood Densities''},
month = {November 12,},
year = {2012},
howpublished = {\url{http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/wood-density-d_40.html}}
}

@misc{Bamboo:Properties,
title = {Luit Nirman},
author = {``Bamboo Structural Material''},
month = {November 2,},
year = {2012},
howpublished = {\url{http://www.assambambooworld.com/bamboo-structural-    material.htm}}
}
```

then

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{url}

\bibliographystyle{plain}

\begin{document}

\Chapter{Bamboo}
Bamboo \cite{Bamboo:Density}\cite{Bamboo:Properties}

\end{document}
```

The output is generally the way I want it except the date appears after the URL instead of before it. I'm trying to stick to APA standards here but the apacite package is a no go. I'm only having trouble with these two sites since they're not really scholarly sources.

and is there any way to stop it from trying to make each reference justified across the whole page? I'd rather the spaces not be inserted and it just cuts off the url to the next line when it no longer fits

Comment: Just a few comments/questions. Omit the commas in the month fields. The month field should not have a day in it. Why put the author in double quotes? The URL of the second entry doesn't look right. Are you sure The author and title of the second entry are the right way around?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `plainurl` bibliography style and use the `url` field, as follows:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{url}

\bibliographystyle{plainurl}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Bamboo}
Bamboo \cite{Bamboo:Density}\cite{Bamboo:Properties}

\bibliography{t}
\end{document}
```

with bibliography file `t.bib`:

```
@misc{Bamboo:Density,
title = {Engineering Toolbox},
author = {``Wood Densities''},
month = {November 12,},
year = {2012},
url = {http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/wood-density-d_40.html},
}

@Misc{Bamboo:Properties,
  title =    {Luit Nirman},
  author =   {``Bamboo Structural Material''},
  month =    {November 2,},
  year =     2012,
  url =  {http://www.assambambooworld.com/bamboo-structural-material.htm},
}
```

More general changes to the bibliography formatting can be obtained using the [custom-bib package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/custom-bib).  In that way you could avoid abusing the standard fields of `bibtex`.

If you still get bad spacing in your bibliography, then you can typeset it ragged right.  This is best done as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{url,ragged2e}

\bibliographystyle{plainurl}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Bamboo}
Bamboo \cite{Bamboo:Density}\cite{Bamboo:Properties}

{\RaggedRight
\bibliography{t}}

\end{document}
```

i.e. loading the `ragged2e` and using the `\RaggedRight` command appropriately bracket so that it only applies to the bibliography.  `\RaggedRight` produces less ragged text than LaTeX's standard `\raggedright` command.